# Python: Create a table that adds a new row and tracks changing variable values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

First, please excuse my misuse of language; I'm relatively new to python, coding, and data science.

I have several python scripts that pull data from various sources (i.e., google sheets, data regularly uploaded to an SFTP server). The data is constantly changing, and I want to track those changes. A simple example follows:

```
students = 10
signed_up = 5
date = datetime.now()
dt_string = date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

data = [[dt_string,students, signed_up]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', '# of students','# students signed up']  )

print(df)
```

Which prints the following data frame:

```
                  date  # of students  # students signed up
0  10/08/2022 20:46:21             10                     5
```

Let's say that I run my other scripts, pull the data again, and the values of "students" and "signed_up" change:

```
students = 11
signed_up = 7
date = datetime.now()
dt_string = date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

data = [[dt_string,students, signed_up]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', '# of students','# students signed up']  )
```

Which prints:

```
                  date  # of students  # students signed up
0  10/08/2022 21:02:15             11                     7
```

Is it possible to script a "running table" (I'm not sure what to call it) that would keep the previous date (10/08/2022 20:46:21) and values for "students" (=10) and "signed_up" (=5) and create a new row with the new date (10/08/2022 21:02:15) and new values for "students" (=11) and "signed_up" (=7)?

Honestly, I've been searching around and don't know where to look -- I'm struggling to identify the terminology I should use to find a solution.

My questions:

1. Does a solution exist?
2. If so, what should I look for?
3. Code examples are always welcome but not necessary.

Any feedback is appreciated -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date', '# of students','# students signed up'])
df.loc[len(df)] = [dt_string1, students1, signed_up1]
df.loc[len(df)] = [dt_string2, students2, signed_up2]
print(df)
```